# macos: how to set a folder only be read by specific apps

Tags: macos, permissions, file-permissions

I'm using the mac os X big sur.

I want to make only specific apps can visit some folder on the disk. How Can I make it ?

Thanks.

Comment: I would think that you will need to use user or group permissions on those folders and run your app as the user you have granted permission to.  All other users (including yourself) will need to be denied access.  This will be a pita as you yourself will need to be logged in as said user to access those folders through the shell or finder.  Perhaps there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

Besides the possible-yet-complicated comment describing permission changes, this is also possible with the built-in macOS controls...

But only if you're willing to accept a LOT of other restrictions.

The Privacy preferences allows you to limit which apps can access which "areas" of your Mac:

[image: privacy]

But, it's not very granular.  I've only seen the 4 choices that are shown under FileZilla in that pic.  So, for example, you could keep your restricted-access-folder in one of those locations (like Downloads) and only grant one app access to that folder.  But, to achieve the security you want, you would have to make sure that you never grant another app access to that same folder.

So, it is possible using these controls, but you may find yourself limited by not having the rest of your apps not be able to access 1 of those 4 sections of your Mac.